# my android program unexpectedly from receive method go to catch block

Tags: java, android

In a part of my android app, there is such a code :

```
            try {                        
                socket.setSoTimeout(100);                                                
                socket.receive(receivedAckPacket);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                socket.send(p);
            }
```

after I debug it, when the flow of the program came to "socket.receive(receivedAckPacket)" my program flow go to catch block! why this thing is happen?

Comment: Because it timed out? I'm not sure what you're asking and what is so "unexpected" about this behavior

Comment: Because that's exactly what it should do if you don't receive anything within 100ms which apparently, you didn't.

Comment: you mean, i must increase 100 in "socket.setSoTimeout(100)  "?

Comment: Because an Exception occurred. Sadly, you're not logging that exception anywhere. A simple `e.printStackTrace()` inside catch block would have printed out the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

and you will see why the exception occured.